# Error con JQuery

Tags: jquery

Tengo esta función

```
<script>
function validarCorreo()
{
    var correo = $("#correoVal").val();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "clases/validar_correo.php",
      data: "correo=" + correo, 
      success: function(data)
      {
        if(data > 0)
        {               
          $("#error_correo").show();
          return false;
        }
        else
        {
         return true;
        }
      }         
   });
}
</script>
```

La pregunta es porque no quiere devolver el true que esta en el else??

Comment: La pregunta seria, porque data siempre es mayor a cero, deberías depurar esa parte y fijarte cuando te tiene que devolver cero o menos que esta pasando

Comment: Aquí valido que el correo que se esta registrando no se se haya registrado anteriormente, entonces si data es mayor a 0 es porque ese correo ya se había registrado anteriormente

Comment: Tendrías que poner el código de como consultas si el correo existe, quizás el problema esta ahí, siempre devuelve que no existe el correo

Comment: ¿Cómo que "no quiere devolver el true"? ¿Dónde estás comprobando el valor devuelto?

Comment: el true o el false te lo esta devolviendo a la función del success de ajax, replantea la estructura de t u codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que entender cómo funcionan las llamadas asíncronas.

La función `validarCorreo` no devuelve ningún valor. De hecho finaliza antes de que se complete la llamada a `validar_correo.php`. La función realiza la llamada y finaliza. Luego, cuando la llamada se completa se ejecuta la función indicada en `success`. Es en ese momento cuando deberías comprobar el valor recibido y entonces, si es adecuado, llamar a la función `insertar`.

Una posible implementación podría ser esta:

```
function validarCorreo()
{
    var correo = $("#correoVal").val();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "clases/validar_correo.php",
      data: "correo=" + correo, 
      success: function(data)
      {
        if(data > 0)
        {               
          $("#error_correo").show();
        }
        else
        {
         insertar();
        }
      }         
   });
}

function insertar()
{
  var nombre = $("#nombreVal").val();
  var correo = $("#correoVal").val();
  var password = $("#passwordVal").val();

  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "clases/insertar_usuario.php",
   data: "nombre=" + nombre + "&correo=" + correo + "&password=" + password, 
   success: function(data)
   {
    if(data > 0)
    {             
     window.location.href = 'registro.php?id=' + data;
    }
    else
    {
      $("#error_cuenta").show();
    }
   }          
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que recibes una respuesta correcta de tu servidor y que es numérica el problema lo tienes en que la propiedad/función `success` de [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) de [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) es [asíncrona](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/funcion_asincrona), esto quiere decir que puedes o no recibir un dato en un futuro, no al instante, por lo tanto necesitas utilizar una manera de recoger tu valor/código a utilizar cuando esté listo el dato. Hay 3 formas extendidas de trabajar asíncronamente, con [Callbacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) *(el que te mostraré)*, con [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise) y con [Observable](http://reactivex.io/).

```
$(function() {

  validarCorreo(callback) {
    var nombre = $("#nombreVal").val();
    var correo = $("#correoVal").val();
    var password = $("#passwordVal").val();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "clases/validar_correo.php",
      data: "correo=" + correo,
      success: function(data) {
        if (data > 0) {
          $("#error_correo").show();
          callback(false);
        } else {
          callback(true);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  validarCorreo(function(validated) {
    console.log(validated);
  });

});
```